# Testing an AngularJs service in a module called 'MyApp.services'

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

The AngularJS book has a complete sample application called 'guthub'. And within that app are defined various services within a module called 'guthub.services'. However, there is no example of how to correctly test a services that is in a different module than 'guthub'. In my application the app module is defined like so:

angular.module('SSAApp', ['SSAApp.services']);

and I am able to access the services module correctly like so:

var services = angular.module('SSAApp.services');

My services work when I run the app. But when I try to run tests via Karma, it fails with an error:
Uncaught Error: No module: SSAApp.services

How do I correctly write a test function such that 'SSAApp.services' can be found? I believe that the code produced by Yeoman assumes that everything is stuck under one module.

Answer (score 0):

Make that that you are running:

```
beforeEach(module('SSAApp.services'));
beforeEach(module('SSAApp'));
```

in the first `describe` block of your tests. I can't remember for sure if you need to run the first one, but you do need to run the second one. Also remember to include the script for `SSAApp.services` in your main index.html used for testing. I've definitely spent time debugging issues like that and realized I forgot to include a file.

Comment: I think I need to restate my problem.

Comment: You only need to provide a beforeEach() on the main module of the app. 

My main problem was with yeoman tools I used to create a stub for the service. Let's say I do this:

yo angular:service myService

The service code will contain a definition of a service call 'Myservice' (note the change in case). However, the test code will then call inject() on a variable called __myService__', which is incorrect. As far as I can see it should be '__Myservice__'. When I change it to that it seems to work. My service instance gets created and I am able to use it in the test code.

Comment: So are you trying to auto-generate the tests as well? Is there anything wrong with renaming the service variable?

Comment: My problem is that from the get-go the yeoman tool for creating a services does it incorrectly. It gets the case wrong of the injected item and so the test stub is broken. I would expect the simple test stub that it creates (which only tests that the constructor of the service was called and returned an object) would pass.